# Force Re-authorization of scopes for Google Add On

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I'm developing an add on for the Google Sheets Add On Marketplace, and I'm somewhat stuck with the validation process that Google requires. They are asking me to re-do the screencapture of the process of authorizing the app for the first time, but since I already gave permission to my add on to run, I am unable to get the permission window to show up again.

Anyone know how can I force Google Sheets to ask for the Oauth permissions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authorization can be manually removed, or removed with code.  Your users should also know how to remove authorization.  You could provide a menu item, or button to users to remove authorization.

### REMOVE AUTHORIZATION WITH CODE

```
function removeAuthorization() {//This must be run from your add-on code
  ScriptApp.invalidateAuth();
}
```

### MANUALLY REMOVE AUTHORIZATION

Make sure that you are not logged into multiple Google accounts.
You need to be logged into just the Google account that installed the add-on.

Go to Manage your Google account:
https://myaccount.google.com/

Go to the security check up
https://myaccount.google.com/security-checkup

Open third party access
Scroll down to the bottom, and click "Show Others"
Remove access for {{Name of your Add-on}}
At this point you've removed authorization to the add-on through your account.

If you have a Workspace account, or some other paid Google account, then you may get the error message:

Uninstall app for domain in admin console

You will need to go into the admin console and delete the app.

Now go back to the add-on and use it and you will be prompted to re-authorize.